# Color in legend doesn't match the color in map

Tags: leaflet, r-leaflet

Basically, I tried to use colors to show the value, however, when I add a legend, the color in legend doesn't match the color in the map.

[image]
    
        `output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        temp<-data[data$coralType==input$type,]
        temp<- aggregate(temp,by=list(temp$location),FUN=mean)
        #print(temp)
        qpal <- colorQuantile("YlOrRd", temp$value,n=6)
        leaflet(temp) %>% addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") %>% 
          addCircleMarkers(~longitude,~latitude,radius 
          =~value*35,color=~qpal(value),
                    label=paste(paste(temp$Group.1,":"),temp$value),fillOpacity 
                     =0.8) %>%
                  addLegend("topright", pal = qpal, values = ~value,
                    title = "Average Rate", opacity = 1)
      })`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but shortly before you posted this question, a similar question appeared on git: https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues/219
I'm having a similar issue but with legends that use nominal data (not ramped gradients).